# Delay when loading review audits

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits

Recently, when I was reviewing the questions and answers in First Answers, First Questions etc, it seems like when Stack Overflow wants to find a "test" for checking if I was focusing and not clicking recklessly, it will load the next question (the "test" question) extremely slowly. It might be related to the test-finding algorithm. It's taking about 10 seconds to load it. Is anybody else also noticing the same problem?

[image]

Comment: It's not a dupe, linked question is a feature-request, this is rightfully a bug report, so I'm clearing the close votes.

Comment: The suggested edits review queue has always taken a while to generate audits (maybe two seconds) so it's very easy to identify them before even seeing them. Lately I think it's been getting even slower (maybe not as extreme as the ten seconds you've seen in your queues though).

Comment: No repro in First Questions. Just got [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/33172242), which had loaded instantly.

Comment: I observed the same in the suggested edits queue recently, with several audits (e.g., [1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33112144) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33118883)). After submitting the prior review task, the UI loaded much longer than usual (~10 seconds is a good estimate), and then showed the audit.

Comment: If I remember correctly almost all audits (maybe even all) from the suggested edit queue are cases of randomly added junk into the text. Maybe those audits get newly generated when an audit is needed, instead of using existing posts/reviews like in other queues? If that's the case, then it would be better to use previous reviews instead, that way they can also provide a wider range of suggested edits, instead of just added random words.

Comment: I also noticed this, it only happens recently.